# Jsonata logic to apply logic inside of array

Tags: jsonata

I've been a developer for some time now and wanted to try out Jsonata. My data comes from a csv file, where the first row contains the fieldnames. Given the following input json:

```
[
    [
        {
            "LineNbr" : 1,
            "Value" : "Desc1"
        },
        {
            "LineNbr" : 1,
            "Value" : "Desc2"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "LineNbr" : 2,
            "Value" : "Value1"
        },
        {
            "LineNbr" : 2,
            "Value" : "Value2"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "LineNbr" : 3,
            "Value" : "Value3"
        },
        {
            "LineNbr" : 3,
            "Value" : "Value4"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "LineNbr" : 4,
            "Value" : "Value5"
        },
        {
            "LineNbr" : 4,
            "Value" : "Value6"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "LineNbr" : 5,
            "Value" : "Value7"
        },
        {
            "LineNbr" : 5,
            "Value" : "Value8"
        }   
    ]
]
```

I would like to create a structure where i map the value of the first row, to each following row inside the array. My desired output would be:

```
[
    {
        "Desc1" : "Value1",
        "Desc2" : "Value2"
    },
    {
        "Desc1" : "Value3",
        "Desc2" : "Value4"  
    },
    {
        "Desc1" : "Value5",
        "Desc2" : "Value6"  
    },
    {
        "Desc1" : "Value7",
        "Desc2" : "Value8"  
    }
]
```

What i been trying so far:

```
(
    $data := $map($, function($v, $i, $a) {
        {

            "rowdata": $map([1..$count($v)], function($vs, $is) {$[0][$is].Value})
        }
    });
)
```

It brings me kinda in the right direction, as the rowdata mapped value is the correct value. But the structure is messed up. Does anyone have an approach on how to solve this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution: I'm filtering the list of rows to exclude the first one, then map them to an array of objects with the help of the [merge function](https://docs.jsonata.org/object-functions#merge):

```
(
  $firstRow := $$[0];
  $dataRows := $$[[1..$count($$)]];
  
  $map($dataRows, function($row) {
    $map($row, function($column, $columnIndex) {{
        $firstRow[$columnIndex].Value: $column.Value
    }}) ~> $merge
  })
)
```

Check it out on the Stedi Playground: https://stedi.link/DJDYwYO

Comment: Wow, that totally nails it! Very nice. I'll try to walk down the documentation to check on what it is you are doing here. Basically the merge statement just squashes the sub array which are being created out of it right?

Comment: Yeah, we are squashing array of single-key objects into a single object with each of those keys, representing a cell in your data.

Comment: So one thing Im wondering about. whats the purpose of the double opening brackets(and closing brackets) :

{{

and 

}}

I know without it it does not work, but is this some sort of object creation?

Comment: The outer curly brackets is for function's body, and the inner curly brackets is for defining an object returned from the function's body (JSONata uses implicit return approach).

This would be functionally the same:
```
function($column, $columnIndex) {(
  $result := {
    $firstRow[$columnIndex].Value: $column.Value
  };
  
  $result
)}
```